# Angular js injection error when app is loaded on browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get this error: `[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=myTmoApp.pdl&p1=Err…rkspace%2Fnetbeans-workspace%2FJsonParsing%2Fweb%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3)`

I have properly injected all services and scopes but still I get this error when I run the app.

Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module("myTmoApppdl", []);


app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, jsonParsingService) {

    var digitalData = digitalData || {};

    digitalData =
            {
                "page": {
                    "pageInfo": {
                        "pageID": "12345",
                        "pageName": "smartphones:samsung-galaxy-s-5",
                        "pageURL": "www.t-mobile.com/products/smartphonesSamsungGalaxyS5",
                        "previousPageURL": "www.t-mobile.com/products/smartphones",
                        "prevPageName": "phones",
                        "version": "1.15",
                        "language": "en-US",
                        "geoRegion": "US",
                        "domain": "t-mobile.com",
                        "responsiveState": "desktop",
                        "timeStamp": "2015-03-23T20:52:23.563Z",
                        "currencyCode": "USD"
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "primaryCategory": "shop",
                        "subCategory": ["smartphones"],
                        "pageType": "product details",
                        "variant": "",
                        "channel": "",
                        "subChannel": "",
                        "flowName": "",
                        "storeID": "",
                        "referringApp": "tapestry"
                    },
                    "search": {
                        "searchTerm": "",
                        "searchResultCount": 0
                    }
                }
            };

    digitalData = JSON.stringify(digitalData);
    console.log("json to be parsed is: " + digitalData);

    $scope.myTxt = "You have not parsed json yet";
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        jsonParsingService.parseMyJson(digitalData);
        $scope.myTxt = "Json parsing complete!";
        console.log("Json parsing complete");
    };
});
```

Service:

```
app.service('jsonParsingService', function () {

    this.parseMyJson = function (json) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        console.log(obj);
    };
});
```

It is just a sample app I am trying to run but unable to figure out what went wrong

Script files:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="parseJson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: why you are using `beta version` which seems old? and problem seems related to `myTmoApp.pdl` module..

Comment: @PankajParkar Even with new version its not working

Comment: try this on the controller app.controller("myCtrl",["$scope", "jsonParsingService", function ($scope, jsonParsingService) { //controller logic here
}]) insert controller code in the middle. Here we pass an array whose elements consist of a list of strings (the names of the dependencies) followed by the function itself, with the dependencies variable names in order

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the service in the following format to the Controller. See the array notation.

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'jsonParsingService',function($scope,jsonParsingService){ 

    //controller code here
}]);
```

See the docs about Dependency Injection  [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: there is no compulsion to have it..unless minifying js files

Comment: Fixed it by having `angular js` file physically in the folder and referring it rather than using cdn. It worked now. Thanks guys anyway

Comment: Yes, but it is still the preferred way according to the documentation even if you are not minifying js files. I have had issues with implicit annotation before, so sticking to this format is better IMO.

Comment: Like mentioned by @PankajParkar Its not necessary to add this. Its just needed when you are minifying. Even in those cases you can use https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `angular.js` wasn't available. Please see a running example in this [bin](https://jsbin.com/jisuxe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)